# Xamarin Forms Custom TabbedRenderer removes TabLayout on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

when I use a Custom Renderer for TabbedPages in Xamarin Forms, the TabLayout is completely removed, and thus only the first Tab is accessible.
This is even the case with an "empty" Custom Renderer like this:

```
public class MyTabbedRenderer: TabbedRenderer
    {
        public MyTabbedRenderer(Context c) : base(c) { }
        public MyTabbedRenderer() : base() { }
    }
```

When I do not use a Custom Renderer for the TabbedPage, the Tablayout renders fine.

Is this a Bug or am I forgetting some code? I am just using a Custom Renderer on Android.

Edit: Xaml of the Page

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="App.Client.View.MyTabbedPage">
    <TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem/>
    </TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage>
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <view:MyView1/>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage>
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <view:MyView2/>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: Let me have a look on your xaml please?

Comment: remove the line "public MyTabbedRenderer() : base() { }" and let us know

Comment: @NickKovalsky sadly does not help

Comment: @G.hakim Added in original post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TabbedRenderer` which I inherited from is a `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.TabbedRenderer`

This renderer uses the old `ActionBar` layout, which deprecated in Android 5.0 Lollipop.

Inheriting from the `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.TabbedPageRenderer`, which utilizes the AppCompat's `Toolbar` and `Tabbar` solves the problem.