# Custom renderer for TabbedPage hides Tabbar

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm currently trying to use a *custom renderer* for my **TabbedPage**.

I actually want to use the *renderer* to change the font of the tabs. Unfortunately the **Tabbar** is not visible when I'm using the *renderer*. Without the *renderer* the **Tabbar** is shown.

Did I forget something?

### My Page:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:***.Views"
        x:Class="***.Views.MainPage"
        xmlns:utils="clr-namespace:***.Utils"
        BarBackgroundColor="Black" BarTextColor="White"
        xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
        android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
        android:TabbedPage.BarTextColor="White"
        android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="Gray"
        android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="White"
        android:TabbedPage.IsSwipePagingEnabled="False"
        CurrentPageChanged="changeTab"
        x:Name="mainTabbedView">

<TabbedPage.Children>
    <NavigationPage Title="1" HeightRequest="20">
        <NavigationPage.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource" >
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="pic1"/>
                <On Platform="Android" Value="pic1"/>
            </OnPlatform>
        </NavigationPage.Icon>
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:NewPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

    <NavigationPage Title="2">
        <NavigationPage.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="pic2"/>
                <On Platform="Android" Value="pic2"/>
            </OnPlatform>
        </NavigationPage.Icon>
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:OtherPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

    <NavigationPage Title="3">
        <NavigationPage.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="pic3"/>
                <On Platform="Android" Value="pic3"/>
            </OnPlatform>
        </NavigationPage.Icon>
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:LastPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

### And the Renderer:

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using ***.Droid;
using Android.Content;


[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]

namespace ***.Droid
{
    class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        public CustomTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that after all you fixed your problem, if not:

### The Solution

In your renderer, in the Android Project, you will have to inherit from `TabbedPageRenderer` instead of from `TabbedRenderer`, as follows

```cs
...
public class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{
  public CustomTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
  {
  }
}
...
```

### Note

A similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52439406/xamarin-forms-custom-tabbedrenderer-removes-tablayout-on-android).